# How to make a Jump Out Box with Constraint and Physics

Tags: physics, normals, constraints

I am making a Jump Out Box which want to prompt a Ball/clown from the box. I am currently using SkretchTo constraints on a mesh called "Spring". However, it is not as real as i expected.

1. when i rotate the clown, it is not aline with the spring normal.
2. It is too hard to simulate the actual behavior of a spring to me by just using the dope sheet
3. I tried to add physics on the spring but it will bounds out from the box. And the physical force are always pointing downwards. I have no idea on solving that.

Hope someone can give me some advice on this. Thanks in advance.

[image]
[image]